# How do I get my bot to mention new users in a welcome message stored in MongoDB, and also read escape sequences?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I want my bot to mention a new user in a welcome message if it is set by moderators to do so. However, I don't know how to get my bot to read `${member}` in the welcome message and know that it's supposed to mention a user there.

Below is what happens when a member joins my guild.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
  if (member.bot) {
    return
  } else {

  const welcome = require('./models/welcomeSchema');

  const welcomeSchema = await welcome.findOne({
    GuildID: member.guild.id
  })

  if (welcomeSchema) {
    const mssg = welcomeSchema.Message;
    const chan = welcomeSchema.ChannelID;
  member.guild.channels.resolve(chan).send(mssg);
  } else if (!welcomeSchema) return
}
});
```

This is my schema for Mongo.

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');

const welcomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
ChannelID: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
Message: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
GuildID: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model(`welcomes`, welcomeSchema);
```

And this is the command that is used to set the welcome message.

```
const welcomeSchema = require('../models/welcomeSchema');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

const mssg = args.slice(2).join(" ")

if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
return message.reply("you lack sufficiant permissions to execute this command.");
}

if (!mssg) {
return message.reply("please state what message you want to welcome new members with.");
} else if (!args[1]) {
return message.reply("please state the channel ID of which you want this message to be sent in.");
}

const data = await welcomeSchema.findOne({
GuildID: message.guild.id
});

if (!data) {

message.channel.send("Welcome message set.");

const newData = new welcomeSchema({
    GuildID: message.guild.id,
    Message: mssg,
    ChannelID: args[1]
})
newData.save();
} else if (data) {

await welcomeSchema.findOneAndRemove({
    GuildID: message.guild.id
})

message.channel.send("Welcome message set.");

const newData = new welcomeSchema({
    GuildID: message.guild.id,
    Message: mssg,
    ChannelID: args[1]
})
newData.save();
}
}

module.exports.config = {
name: "setWelcome",
aliases: []
}
```

Would I have to make my bot take the data in the database and translate it to Javascript, then send the message? If so, how do I do that?

Please let me know if I need to provide more details. I don't exactly know how to word this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `member.guild.channels.resolve(chan).send(mssg);` with `client.channels.channels.cache.get(chan).send(mssg);`